# Essential Graphics - Media Replacement issue

Tags: video, after-effects, animation

I was trying to improve some of my work templates using *Essential Graphics*, which I absolutely love, for the first time I'm adding the **media replacement** function to it but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried images, videos and an actual AE placeholder but it just doesn't seem to accept any of my assets.

Check [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/9Ag5QdkP9rA?t=330) at **05:30** where she successfully achieves what I'm trying to do.

I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered the same issue, I'm probably doing something wrong but I don't seem to see where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though *Essential Graphics* have been available for a few years now, *Replace Media* is available around **After Effects v18.0**, be sure to update your app.